# NAudio volume in ASIO

Tags: c#, asio, naudio

If I wanna change output volume I should not use `IWavePlayer.Volume` property right? I should just change (multiply by factor) output samples in `WaveProvider` right? OK, it is fine for `WaveOut` and `DirectSoundOut` because you can control them from Windows Volume Mixer. If I put volume in Volume Mixed at 100%, and send untouched samples from `WaveProvider` I will achieve 100% of soundcard volume. But if I use `AsioOut` I cannot change volume in Windows Mixer. OK fine, but ASIO system don't play sound at 100% sound card volume. I hear sound very quiet. How to tell ASIO to play audio at 100% sound card output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASIO should play at full volume by default. With ASIO you control the output volume yourself by adjusting the values of the samples that are sent. Your ASIO control panel might allow you to send special commands to your specific sound-card, but the ASIO API itself is very limited and doesn't include a volume function.